# TTS Installed voices in wp8.1

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, text-to-speech, speech

I'm trying to implement kind of translation application.

I consider using the TTS to "speak" the translated text, but when I tried to get the installed voices I get only 2 (en-US male and female).

I see in the MSDN that:

"Only Microsoft-signed voices installed on the system can be used to generate speech. If no language is specified, the voice that most closely matches the language selected by the user in the Language control panel is loaded."

So my question is: how can I get additional voices besides those who already installed in the device?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the MSDN article you quoted, the user can add voices by installing appropriate languages in the control panel. Apps will then have access to these voices.

Apps cannot add voices or use voices beyond what are installed on the device.